# How do I find the average of double numbers entered at the command line?

Tags: c, average

I have to find the average of double numbers that the user inputs at the command line, so my program should work with any amount of inputs. I understand that I have to find the sum of all of the numbers and then divide by the number of inputs.

I was thinking, to find the number of inputs, I would use sscanf to read "char *num" in my argument list. Because sscanf returns the characters read. And then I was thinking of using that to divide the sum by to get the average. But I'm having trouble with my code. :(

```
#include <stdio.h>

void average(int arg_list, char *num[])
{
   int x;
   double sum, average;

   x = sscanf(num, "%s\n", &x);

   for (int i = 0; i != '\0'; i++)
   {
      sum = sum + num[i];
   }

   average = sum/x;
   printf("%lf\n", average);;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if (argc == 0)
   {
      perror("Error!\n");
   }

   average(argc, argv);
}
```

Specifically, when I try to compile my program, the compiler complains about the "sscanf" and the sum. :/

Comment: One problem is that your format string in `sscanf` is using a `%s` to scan an integer. Did you try `%d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"%s"` reads a string. you want to read a double out of the string, so you should use `"%lf"`. *inside* the loop:

```
double sum = 0; //you forgot to initialize
//start from i=1, not 0; the first argument is the program's name
for (int i = 1; i < arg_list; i++) {
    double x;
//from the i'th argument, read a double, into x :
    sscanf(num[i], "%lf", &x);
    sum += x;
}
average = sum/(arg_list-1);
```

you should also fix your check:

```
if (argc <= 1) {
   perror("Error!\n");
}
```

Comment: Oh! I see...is sum += x shorthand for something?

Comment: `sum += x` <=> `sum = sum + x`

Comment: is there a benefit to using `sscanf` over something like `atoi`?

Comment: `sscanf` is flexible, easy, and familiar. `atoi` is a *bad idea*, since it has undefined behavior if unsuccessful. `strtol` is much better, but feels a bit awkward to use, for me.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use atoi. :( Oh! And, one question, what I'm trying to do is to read the string in order to get the total number of inputs. Could I do a sscanf for the entire string outside of the loop?

Comment: the total number of inputs is `argc-1`.

Comment: He asked to sum double numbers, but in this example, you define x as integer and read integers at sscanf using %d. You should change that to use double, that is:
double x;
sscanf(num[i], "%f", &x);

Comment: @Ishmar you are right. I did not see he wrote 'double numbers', so I assumed the input is integers, following the OP's original logic. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void average(int arg_list, char *num[])
{
   double sum = 0, average;//sum : 0 initialize
   int i;
   for (i = 1; i < arg_list; i++){
      sum = sum + atof(num[i]);
   }
   average = sum/(--i);
   printf("%lf\n", average);;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if (argc < 2)//include program name argv[0], argc == 1 even when only ./a.out
   {
      perror("Error!\n");
      return -1;
   }

   average(argc, argv);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `atof` is a bad idea, too. and `sum/(--i)` is an odd way to say `argc-1`.

Comment: atof is not bad separately. It would have been deleted if worst if. You will not use `argc-1` if you're considering the need for inspection of value-if.

Comment: `atof` has cases of undefined behavior. I don't understand the rest of your comment.

Comment: @Elazar You should count the number that have gone through the test if you are thinking about the health of the numbers-if.

Comment: You did not do it in your answer, and you should probably raise an error for bad input, not tolerate it. This is what the OP does in `main()`. And you won't know if the input is bad if you use `atof`.